# Mostrar imagen por URL en Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

Tengo una app en la cual me muestra datos de una **`API`**. Realicé un servicio que obtiene los datos, en donde `URL(string = "")` es la **url** de la **`API`**:

```
class Webservice {

func getAllMatches(completion: @escaping ([Matches.Matchs]?) -> ()) {

    guard let url = URL(string: "API")
        else {
            fatalError("URL is not correct!")
    }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in

        let matchs = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Matches.Matchs].self, from: data!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(matchs)
        }
    }.resume()
}

}
```

Hasta ahí no hay problemas. Luego realicé un **`ViewModel`** en el cual se establecieron los campos de la **API**:

```
class MatchListViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var matches = [MatchViewModel]()


init() {
    fetchMatch()


}

func fetchMatch() {

    Webservice().getAllMatches { matches in

        if let matches = matches {
            self.matches = matches.map(MatchViewModel.init)
        }
    }
}



}

class MatchViewModel {

let id = UUID()

var match: Matches.Matchs

init(match: (Matches.Matchs)) {
    self.match = match
}


var championship: String {
    return self.match.championship.name
}

var local_Name: String {
    return self.match.local.name
}

var local_Image: String  {
    return self.match.local.image
}

var local_goals: Double {
    return self.match.local_goals
}

var local_penalty_goals: Double {
    return self.match.local_penalty_goals
}
var stadium_Name: String {
    return self.match.stadium.name
}


}
```

Resulta que, en la **`API`**, se encuentra un campo que muestra una imagen, que está contenida en una **URL**, dejo ejemplo:

```
"local":{  
     "slug":"nombre",
     "name":"nombre",
     "short_name":"nombre",
     "image":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/funx-futbol/dashboard/ad.png"
  },
```

Mi pregunta es:

¿Cómo puedo mostrar esa imagen por medio de esa **URL**? En si, la consulta a la **`API`** funciona, ya que me trae la información que requiero, pero necesito que me muestre la imagen por ese link, del cual no lo he logrado.

Gracias por leer!

Comment: te recomiendo mucho el framework de SDWEBIMAGE, aparte de ser muy sencillo de utilizar optimiza el rendimiento de la memoria al usar imágenes, o si no quieres implementar frameworks, te recomiendo este video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIgqHLTZ_a4  es en swift 2 o 3 pero no cambia mucho a lo que es hoy swift 5

Answer (score 0):

usa Session dataTask para obtener la data de la imagen y la pasas como UIIMage(data: imageData)

```
 Session.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
          let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
          if let error = error { 
             print(error.localizeDescription)
          }
          if httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                guard let data = data else { return }
                let image = UIImage(data: data)

        // ya puedes usar la imagen  normalmente te pide procesar en el hilo principal solo usa el DispatchQueue.main.async
                self.imageView.image = image
          }

    }.resume()
```